# Show Specific Footer Widget for Specific Pages

Tags: php, widgets

I registered a new footer widget with this code.

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => esc_html__( 'Footer Sidebarprestige', 'realtor' ),
  'id' => 'footer-sidebarprestige',
  'description' => esc_html__( 'Widgets in this area will be shown in Footer Area.', 'realtor' ),
  'class'=>'',
  'before_widget'=>'<li id="%1$s"  class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget'=>'</li>',
  'before_title' => '<h5>',
  'after_title' => '</h5>'
));
```

I called it in my footer.php file like this:

```
<ul class="row">

   <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar'); ?>

 </ul>

  <ul class="row">

   <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebarprestige'); ?>

 </ul>
```

The 'footer-sidebar' is original widget and the 'footer-sidebarprestige' is the one I added. The way it is now if I add a widget to the widget area I added it shows up under the original one and I understand why.

What I am trying to do. Call the widget area that I added only for certain page ID's. Basically, only on called page ID's show newly created footer widget and not show the original widget area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve this:

A. Use CSS to hide and show widgets based on which page you are on. This is fine as a workaround, but it isn't really solving your problem, especially if you have lots of pages/widgets.

B. Call a different widget area in your template file with conditional logic

```
<ul class="row">
   <?php if(is_page('my-page')){
      dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebarprestige');
   } ?> 
</ul>
```

C. Use a plugin like [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) to use conditional logic on the widgets themselves. You can then add a condition like `is_page('my-page')` for displaying the widget, on a widget-per-widget basis.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to display a widget on specific pages, right?
You could use a plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-context/

Comment: Hi Remzi. Thanks for responding. Prefer not to use a Plugin. Especially from what I read that the widget plugin like Widget Logic possible security breach

Comment: I understand, there are a lot of bad ones out there. I have used several widget plugins and this one is small and simple. You could look at the source code, it also open source: https://github.com/kasparsd/widget-context-wporg

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with below code:

```
<ul class="row">

   <?php if ( is_page( 1111 )) : ?>
   <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebarprestige'); ?>
   <?php else :?>
   <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>

  </ul>
```

Thank you Pim, you sent me on the right track to get my answer